# Mootools: HtmlTable really multiselect

Tags: javascript, mootools, html-table, mootools-more

I have a table parsed to Mootools HtmlTable class. using:

```
var table = new HtmlTable($('htmlTableElement'), {
 sortable: true,
 parsers: ['string','number','numberLax','floatLax'],
 selectable: true,
 allowMultiSelect: true,
 shiftForMultiSelect: false,
 classRowSelected: 'selectedRow'
});
table.sort(1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LMQ75/

What I want to do is, to select different rows by clicking on them. It's working pretty fine for one row and also using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> -key you can also select more than one row in an order. But how is it possible not to deselect the selected rows when clicking on another row? So that I can select e.g. two rows that are not connected?

I also figured out, that a row can be selected by clicking on it, but not deselected. Can I change this behaviour that first click selects a row and second click deselects a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised of myself, I found a simple and easy solution, just adding this lines of code below table initialization:

```
$('htmlTableElement').getElements('tbody tr').addEvent('click',function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 table.toggleRow(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LMQ75/2/